# how to convert 10.5 month to 315 days in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

how to convert 10.5 months to 315 days in Postgresql?

I have a column with 11.5, 6, 4.5 or Null value, etc, I would like to convert them to display as days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
postgres=# select extract (epoch from interval '10.5 months' ) / 24/60/60;
┌──────────────────────┐
│       ?column?       │
╞══════════════════════╡
│ 315.0000000000000000 │
└──────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

you can write custom function

```
create or replace function to_days(interval)
returns interval as $$
  select extract(epoch from $1) / (24 * 60 * 60) * interval '1day';
$$ language sql;

postgres=# select to_days('10.5 months');
┌──────────┐
│ to_days  │
╞══════════╡
│ 315 days │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks  so much for your detailed answer, can I use simple sql to solve it, because I use it in Kettle, and I can't use these function in kettle

Comment: @Elsa - sure - just use a formula `(extract(epoch from column_name) / (24 * 60 * 60) * interval '1day')`